# how to download file from other server using mvc asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

How can i download file from other server and save it at my own using mvc asp.net with c#?

Comment: English please; not that many people here speak Polish.

Comment: How do you want to download the file? Are you downloading it from a Windows Share? An URL? FTP?

Comment: I want to download it form url and i have to send password and username over get metod

Comment: Just to clarify, do you want users to download files from the server running the code, or do you want the server running the code to download files from another (altogether) server?

Answer (score 3):

I am only able to read your title, nevertheless:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadFile("http://your-address.com/FileToDonwload.ext", "c:\PathToTheFileToCreate");
```

should do what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

i'd use the **System.Web.Mvc.FilePathResult** along the following lines:

```
// most controller logic ommitted
public ActionResult DownloadFile(int fileID)
{
    // in this example fileID would map to a file location in the database
    var item = _repository.GetByKey(fileID);

    // item.DocType would equal "application/msword" / "image/jpeg" etc, etc;
    return File(item.DocumentLocation, item.DocType);        
}
```

**[edit]** - ooops, just realised that this will only work on same server/domain, but have left for reference